# Using parent data in Form Actions in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

Parent's `+laytout.server.ts` data could be gotten throw parent() method coming from load function. ([described in docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-parent-data))

**Question:**
Is it possible to access that data in [Form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#loading-data)?

```js
// src/routes/account/+page.server.js

/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export async function load({parent}) {
  const {IMPORTANT_DATA} = await parent()

  return {
    IMPORTANT_DATA
  };
}
 
/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {
  logout: async (event) => {
    // I would like to access IMPORTANT_DATA here
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm in need of this same exact thing. Unfortunately, [it doesn't seem to have access to the parent object](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/8808bebb20778d81e016efeafd45df661bfa05db/packages/kit/types/index.d.ts#L504-L578). I'm not sure about he reason but I presume it is because, typically, the layouts are run for GET requests while the form actions can run for POST requests too (those are very different mindsets although it could be up to the developer). While I love SvelteKit, I can't help but thing that sometimes, it is too opinionated.

Answer (score 1):

Form actions cannot access data from `load` functions. Either from the current page or from the `parent` layout(s). The `load` functions do not run on the form submission request.

[Hooks](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks) do run on form submission requests, so one solution is to fetch `IMPORTANT_DATA` there and add it to `locals`. If fetching `IMPORTANT_DATA` is expensive or not used on other pages, that may not be a great solution as it will get fetched on every single request, including page loads for other pages. In that case, it would be better to fetch the data again directly in your form action (`activeaccount`).

Answer (score -1):

for access a 'IMPORTANT_DATA' where in my case is sessioninfo from actions, i seted in file src/hooks.server.js `event.locals.sessioninfo = user;`

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
import  jwt  from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from "$lib/model/user";
import {
  SECRET_SESSION_HASH
} from '$env/static/private';


export async function handle({cookies, event, resolve }) {

  
  // set sesion data
  let user = null;
  try {
    let ckses = event.cookies.get('sessionid');

    const {email} = jwt.verify(ckses,SECRET_SESSION_HASH);
    user =  await User.getByEmail(email);
    delete user.password;
    event.locals.sessioninfo = user;

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("no session");
  }

  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
}
```

then
in +page.server.js

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').LayoutServerLoad} */
/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */


import {fail, redirect} from "@sveltejs/kit"
import User from "$lib/model/user";

export async function load({locals}) {
  let {sessioninfo} = locals;
  if (sessioninfo) {
    if (sessioninfo.roles.includes("sudo")) {
      let users =  await  User.gets();
      return {users};
    }
  }
  throw redirect(302, "/cuenta");
}

export const actions = {
  activeaccount: async ({locals, cookies, request}) => {
    let {sessioninfo} = locals;
    if (sessioninfo) {

      if (sessioninfo.roles.includes("sudo")) {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const id       = formData.get("id");
        const status   = formData.get("status");
        let res = await User.update({status},id);
        return {res};
      }

    }
  },
}
```

Comment: The thing is, your example will compute on each request, whereas layout's data would not be refetched until manually invalidated or layout itself changes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is an alternative for get IMPORTANT_DATA in **actions** because i don't found an example for do that, if you no need compute on each request, you can add a conditional that depend of header request or url